# How so I return multiple JSON values to multiple text views?

Tags: android, json

I did research for `JSON`. But only found tutorials for `JSONArray`, not how to make allow multiple text views for a `JSONObject`. Should I have another method, add parameters or what?

This is my `JSON`,

```
{
    "name": "iss",
    "id": 25544,
    "latitude": -16.621580566205,
    "longitude": -22.573425077475,
    "altitude": 403.33965999684,
    "velocity": 27615.932538565,
    "visibility": "daylight",
    "footprint": 4421.7128198729,
    "timestamp": 1478617317,
    "daynum": 2457701.1263542,
    "solar_lat": -16.808913358406,
    "solar_lon": 310.46294067763,
    "units": "kilometers"
}
```

Here is the code if you want to see it,

```
public class IsstatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String longitSt;
    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    TextView latitude;
    TextView longitude;
    String lat;
    String longit;
    JSONObject jobj = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.isstatus);
        latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);

        new retrievedata().execute();
    }

    class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... args) {
            jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");
            try {
                lat = "latitude: " + jobj.getString("latitude");
                longit = "longitude :" + jobj.getString("longitude");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return lat;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String lat) {
            latitude.setText(lat);
            longit.setText(longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are u trying to achieve?

Comment: rotected void onPostExecute(String lat,String long) {

       latitude.setText(lat);
       longit.setText(longitude);




   }

Comment: What is the issue with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong 
In onPostExecute() instead of longit.setText(longitude) use longitude.setText(longit) as longitude is a TextView reference and longit is a String.It goes like this
1. Use String lat and long as global variables.

2. After making network call set lat and long values.
3. In onPostExecute setText for your textviews.

Comment: @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String lat) {
            latitude.setText(lat);
            longitude.setText(longit);



            




        }
    }
}

Comment: is it working now

Comment: I fixed it but it has an error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: longitude is null in your code.Take a look at onCreate method.Add longitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.something);

Comment: Thank you very much